# How to change int value in block?

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks

How change int value in block, I have this :

```
__block long long size = -1;
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
{

    ALAssetRepresentation * rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
    size = [rep size];
    //here showed normal value
    NSLog(@"needed size : %lld",size);
};
ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
[assetslibrary assetForURL:self.tmpVideoURL 
               resultBlock:resultblock
              failureBlock:nil];

//but here remaind -1
NSLog(@"out block value : %lld",size);
```

Comment: If this is your real code, then the problem is that the Block isn't being executed at that point, just defined. Where exactly is the second `NSLog` located in your code? Are you actually seeing "needed size" appear in the log before "out block value", or are they the other way around?

Comment: One second.. i'll update it soon !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're sending that block off to be executed sometime later, after the `assetForURL:...` method has done its work, which it's doing *asynchronously*. It's most likely on a background thread or queue, allowing the method itself to return immediately while the work continues.

So the method `assetForURL:...` returns *before* your `resultBlock` has run, meaning the value hasn't been changed yet, by the time you get to the second `NSLog`. Everything's working fine; you're just checking the value too early.